# Variable Sample can not be resolved to variable

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

// double the first even number greater than 3
public class FirstDouble {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9);
    /*  int result = 0;
        for(int e : numbers)
        {
            if(e>3 && e%2==0)
            {
                result = e*2;
                break;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(result);
        */
        System.out.println(
                numbers.stream()
                .filter(Sample::isGT3)
                .filter(Sample::isEven)
                .map(Sample::doubleIt)
                .findFirst());
        }

    public boolean isGt3(int number) {
        return number > 3;
    }

    public boolean isEven(int number) {
        return number % 2 == 0;
    }

    public int doubleIt(int number) {
        return number * 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Three modifications are needed to make the code compile:

- Rename `Sample` to `FirstDouble` in order to properly reference the class
- Rename the method `isGt3` to `isGT3`
- As the methods are referenced statically, add the `static` modifier to `isGT3`, `isEven` and `doubleIt`

After that, it prints out `Optional[12]`. If only the number should be printed, add a `get` after `findFirst`.

Comment: Thank you so much.